# Safe publication

Tags: java

Could not understand methods 1 and 3 as to how it helps to achieve safe publication. Can anyone help me understand this with an example if possible.

> To publish an object safely, both the
>   reference to the object and the
>   object's state must be made visible to
>   other threads at the same time. A
>   properly constructed object can be
>   safely published by:
>
> - Initializing an object reference from    a static initializer
> - Storing a reference to it into a     volatile field or AtomicReference
> - Storing a reference to it into a  final field of a properly constructed 
>     object
> - Storing a reference to it into a     field that is properly guarded by a
>     lock.

Comment: That would be 2 questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are specific synchronization rules in the Java memory model that define the "happens-before" relationships in a Java program that determine when an application is guaranteed to see "fresh" values of the variables it references.  The "safe publication" methods achieve safe publication as a logical consequence of the synchronization rules, and other rules set out in the Java Language Specification.

1. [JLS section 12.4.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4.2) specifies the procedure by which classes are initialized.  The synchronization that occurs in this procedure is presumably sufficient to guarantee safe publication.
2. [JLS section 17.4.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.4) bullet point 2 deals with volatile fields.  This property of AtomicReferences is a consequence of the behaviour specified in the javadocs.
3. [JLS section 17.5.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.5)
4. [JLS section 17.4.](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/memory.html#17.4.4) bullet point 1

To really understand this stuff, you need to read all of JLS section 17, carefully, a number of times.

Comment: Yes, read it once. was very helpful, need to read again. thanks for the answer and the suggestion.